# python lambda function can't import file with lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

cdk code:

```
from aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha import PythonFunction

sns_topic_notifications = _sns.Topic(
    self, "SNSNotifications", topic_name="notifications"
)
lambda_handle_notification = PythonFunction(
    self,
    "NotificationsHandler",
    entry="../my_server",
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    handler="handle_notification",
    index="a.py",
    role=role_lambda_general,
)
sns_topic_notifications.add_subscription(
    _sns_subscriptions.LambdaSubscription(lambda_handle_notification)
)
```

I also have this in the same file:

```
lambda_hello = PythonFunction(
    self,
    "HelloHandler",
    entry="../my_server",
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    handler="lambda_handler",
    index="app.py",
    role=role_lambda_general,
)
```

Both `a.py` and `app.py` are in the same folder under `my_server`. The `lambda_handler` in `app.py` works ok, but for the `handle_notification` in `a.py` I get this error:
`Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'a': No module named 'my_server'`

Comment: Can you clarify - you said both files are in the same folder, but the entry points to two different folders.

Comment: @gshpychka sorry, edited the code. Both to my_server.

Comment: The issue is within the `a.py` file.

Comment: what's the issue..?

Comment: the a.py file throws an error you mean?

Comment: `No module named 'my_server'`. Check to see what modules `a.py` is importing and add that code to the question.

Comment: OK I think the problem was that in a.py I had 'from my_server.models import...'. I works locally, but in the cloud what works is 'from models import...'

Comment: Good you got to the problem. It would be easier to solve if you had posted the code for a.py

Comment: Your local dev path will be different from the path within the lambdas runtime. youve run into a common pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PythonFunction` from `aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha` that is in [experimental phase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda_python_alpha.html) [image]

Still, it should work for a simple python lambda function like yours. The problem seems to indicate that the dependencies of a.py are not resolved in the directory you tell it under the `entry` property.
[image]

We don't know which package a.py imports, but **before launching your CDK application you must install the dependencies that appear in** *a.py*.

Let's imagine for a moment that your a.py looked like :

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("Hi, I imported sqlalchemy and pandas library :)")
```

You should move with your terminal to the directory "my_server" and install python dependencies:

`pip install sqlachemy`

`pip install pandas`

With this, you won't see the error again
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'a': No module named 'my_server'` since you will have uploaded the whole folder, and the dependencies will be found there.

However, this has to be done carefully, because the installation of dependencies depends on the architecture of your host system. If your host is x86/x64, and lambda is arm, this will not work.

---

I would recommend you to **migrate to official** and not experimental **aws cdk lambda function** `aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function`. Here you can find the adapted version of your `a` python function.

```
function_lambda = aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function(
    self,
    "NotificationsHandler",
    runtime=aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
    handler="../my_server.a.lambda_handler",
    memory_size=256,
    timeout=aws_cdk.Duration.seconds(29),
    role=role_lambda_general,
    log_retention=aws_cdk.aws_logs.RetentionDays.ONE_MONTH,
    environment={
        "LOG_LEVEL": "DEBUG"
    },
    code=aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Code.from_asset(
        path="../my_server",
        bundling=aws_cdk.BundlingOptions(
            image=aws_cdk.DockerImage.from_registry("public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.8:latest-x86_64"),
            command=[
                "bash",
                "-c",
                "pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && rsync -r . /asset-output"
            ]
        ),
    )
)
```